# Swift-4 : How to fetch data using POST request with Parameters in URLSession with "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsurlsession, swift4.2

Friends, I've gone through lot's of examples, which are available on S.O. Though I haven't received proper answer, and still I'm facing issue in getting data via api request using URLSession with Post request & passing parameters with it.

First, I'ld like to show you, what I have. tried till now...

```
func requestApiCall(){

    let renewal_id = ""
    let policy_no = ""
    let client_name = ""
    let client_id = ""
    let product_name = ""
    let created_date_from = ""
    let created_date_to = ""
    let policy_expiry_from = ""
    let policy_expiry_to = ""

    self.parameters = ["renewal_id":renewal_id,"policy_no":policy_no,"client_name":client_name,"client_id":client_id,"product_name":product_name,"created_date_from":created_date_from,"created_date_to":created_date_to,"policy_expiry_from":policy_expiry_from,"policy_expiry_to":policy_expiry_to]

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let Url = String(format: "http://myapi-url");
    let serviceUrl = URL(string: Url)
    var request = URLRequest(url: serviceUrl!)
    print(request.url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.timeoutInterval = 60

    request.httpBody  = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters!, options: [])

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            print(response!)
        }
        else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }

        print(response!)
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, let receivedData = data
            else {
                print("error: not a valid http response")
                return
        }

        switch (httpResponse.statusCode)
        {
        case 200: //The request was fulfilled
            let response = NSString (data: receivedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            if response == "SUCCESS"
            {
                print("Network - HandShaking Successfull...!!!")
            }
            else{
                print("Network - HandShaking is not successfull...!!!")
            }

        case 400:
            print("response-status - 400 : The request had bad syntax or was inherently impossible to be satisfied.")
        case 500:
            print("\nresponse-status - 500 : Internal Server Error...!!!")
        default:
            print("response-status - Unknown : Received Response =>  \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

After running above function, I'm getting httpResponse.statusCode = 500

But when I run this in postman, I get response properly, as aspected.

[Postman Api-Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJHec.png)

Also I have tried to generate code-snippets through postman...which are as follow...

```
func postmanSnippetApiCall(){
    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "Postman-Token": "5d571157-86c5-4eac-ba6d-b00779ae5dbd"
    ]

    let postData = NSMutableData(data: "renewal_id=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    postData.append("&policy_no=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    postData.append("&client_name=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    postData.append("&client_id=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    postData.append("&product_name=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    postData.append("&created_date_from=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    postData.append("&created_date_to=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    postData.append("&policy_expiry_from=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    postData.append("&policy_expiry_to=".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    postData.append("&undefined=undefined".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://myapiurl")! as URL,
                                      cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpBody = postData as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse)
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
}
```

But in **postman generated code snippet**, I'm receiving error on this line i.e `request.httpBody = postData as Data` and **error** is this one : `Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableData' to type 'Data' in coercion`

If I use thirdParty Library i.e **Alamofire**, then I'm able to get data very easily.

**Alamofire code snippet...runs perfectly..& gives proper response.**

```
func apiRequestByAlamofire(){
        let urlString = "http://myapiurl"

        let params: [String: Any]? = ["renewal_id":"","policy_no":"","client_name":"","client_id":"","product_name":"","created_date_from":"","created_date_to":"","policy_expiry_from":"","policy_expiry_to":""]

        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON { response in
            print(response) //Here getting perfect response successfully...!!!
        }

    }
```

**But still I'm struggling this via URLSession...!!!**

And still I doubt, that why I'm getting too much problems, while doing with URLSession.

Friends for above my doubt, please I'm open to your suggestions, as well as please help me out to understand it.

Don't know, where am I going wrong. please help me out here.

Comment: There is an option of generating Code snippets in postman, try that out.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too...but not able to resolve it. Getting response status as 500.

Comment: If you try the Objective-C Code generated by Postman it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @Larme can you help me out in this.

Comment: @Larme yes it does work

Comment: And what’s the Postman generated code? What’s the difference between yours?

Comment: Please check my updated Question.

Comment: Replace `let postData = NSMutableData(data:)` with `let postData = Data(); postData.append(theFirstParam renewal_id  as the other Ones)`, then `request.httpBody = postData`. Now, do: `let httpBodyString = String(data: request.httpBody, encoding: .utf8); print("Body in Postman: \(httpBodyString))`, in your code, do the same. Compare what's the body you are using and the one in your code, you'll see it's different. Construct your own body param the same way as the working one.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you simple function, You can edit this function as per your requirement. You can change your URL and params as well. And in the response, I have written two-line if you are taking JSON array from the server then use the first one if you are taking object then second one else remove Both lines.

```
func abc()  {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "Your URL")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "param_name_one=\( value_1 )&param_name_two=\(value_2)&........."
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        if(error != nil){
            // Show Error Message
        } else{
            do {
                //For JSON ARRAY
                let jsonItem  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray
                let json = jsonItem[0] as AnyObject
               //For JSON object 
                let json_object  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
                print(json_object)
                
            } catch {
                
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume();
}
```

Comment: No, I haven't received data, but yes I'm getting status code 200, but no response yet. 

I'm sending parameter's with only keys, there is no value.

Comment: This is only the technique for fetching the data, Please try to debug your code at server side and edit your question with your response, whatever you are getting from the server. You can use PostMan for this. or take a guidance from your backend developer.

Comment: But in Alamofire, I'm getting data properly. So what is the issue with URLSession

Comment: try to print your response and then try to print next stage data!, Only debugging is the best solution for that, because same code is working on my system.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and fighting a lot with this I have come up with this solution:

```swift
        guard var components = URLComponents(url: URL(string: "http://example.com")!, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
            else { fatalError("Couldn't create URLComponents") }
        
        components.queryItems = params.map { k, v in URLQueryItem(name: k, value: v) }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: baseUrl.appendingPathComponent(path.rawValue))
        request.httpBody = Data(components.query!.utf8)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

The "example.com" can literally be that, because I'm just using `URLComponents` to encode the parameters.